# How to create one field (dropdown list), show list by $session

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.1

How to create one field (dropdown list) where list of Pracownik is shown by idPlachta (session variable)?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $session = $options['session'];

    $builder
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('idPracownik');   //this place
}


public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Przydzial',
        'session' => null,
    ));
}


public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'appbundle_przydzial';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own pracownik choice type and use it any where

```
class PracownikChoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var SessionInterface
     */
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefault('class', 'Your\Entity\ClassName')
            ->setDefault('query_builder', function (EntityRepository $repository) {
                $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('o');

                $queryBuilder
                    ->select('o')
                    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('o.plachtaId', ':id'))
                    ->setParameter('id', $this->session->get('idPlachta'))
                ;

                return $queryBuilder;
            })
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

To inject `session` service to this form type, you should create it as a service:

```
<service id="your.service.id" class="Your\Namespace\Form\Type\PracownikChoiceType">
    <argument type="service" id="session" />

    <tag name="form.type" />
</service>
```

Now, you can use this form type any where and do not needs to build `$choices` list.

```
// Usage with `FormInterface` instance
$form
    ->add('plachta', PracownikChoiceType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Plachta',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'style' => 'margin-bottom: 15px'
        )
    ))
;

// Usage with `FormBuilderInterface` instance
$formBuilder
    ->add('plachta', PracownikChoiceType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Plachta',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'style' => 'margin-bottom: 15px'
        )
    ))
;
```

Comment: Ok. I'm creating session in this code: https://pastebin.com/khzjkeaP and I can use it in my controller

public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $plachta = $request->getSession()->get('plachta');

How can I use this session in your code?

sorry, I'm beginner

Comment: @wluczykuj Look at my updated answer with example usage.

Comment: could You please look my post?

Comment: The tag name must be `form.type`, not `form.type.przydzial`. This tag name will be used for all custom form type.

Comment: Ok, now is form.type, but i have got new warning: 
https://pastebin.com/U4papXv7, do You understand my pic? (~~50/50)

Comment: The error is clear enough, you forget to use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface` in your form type

Comment: Yes, sorry. But i have got new warning Class AppBundle\Form\EntityRepository does not exist, 
i searched this but i can't find this line

Comment: Again, `EntityRepository` stored at `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` not in `AppBundle\Form\EntityRepository` and your code in the snippet is totally wrong. It seems you don't understand what I'm trying to suggest and lacking of basic knowledge about Symfony form.

Comment: You right, I don't understand how i should do it. I want to learn it becouse I need it.

Comment: I added use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository; and I have got : https://pastebin.com/VRFRsUTk